# Rotate pseudo element with transition not working in Safari

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have an element in an :after pseudo element. On click, this will rotate with a smooth transition.

Here is my code pen http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/ABgJq - This works in Chrome, Firefox and Opera on a mac, but does not work on Safari.

My code...

HTML

```
<div class="expand"></div>
```

CSS

```
.expand:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
} 

.expanded:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.expand').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Would like to know what I am doing wrong.

I have seen on this site, it is working fine in Safari http://www.barrelny.com/blog/ (Click on the 'View by Category' dropdown to see the arrow rotate with transition. I realise here they do not use a pseudo selector, but is there a way to do it with a pseudo class? As it works in other browsers just not Safari?

Also, this needs to be in an :after as the example I have given is a simplified version of the problem

Comment: The arrow on the page you linked is no pseudo element.

Comment: sorry just updated my post

Comment: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BkhFI
This is a test case to see if the browser supports animation of pseudo elements. Do they animate? If yes, there is hope, if no, then it's not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks Nirazul for providing that, it's what I was afraid of, but at least I know now

Comment: Damn. Mobile Safari is the new IE6. SO MANY BUGS

Answer (score 5):

Transitioning of pseudo elements is a fix that is slowly making its way into browsers.

I'm running the latest safari beta: v6.1 (8537.54.1) - it is working fine for me.  Looks like you'll see the fix land soon.

CSS-Tricks has a post that is being updated as the fix lands: [Transitions and Animations on CSS Generated Content](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)

It is currently showing as unsupported for Safari 6.0.2 and down: [Bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23209)

Comment: Thanks for this crucial info. Yes I am running Safari 6.0.5. So it seems I can either wait for 6.1 or see if there is a way to do without using :after. Thanks again

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/ see this its fixed when ever new safari version comes it would have this issue resolved.